# Is 50Hz noticably worse for eyes than 60Hz on a 4K monitor?

Tags: eyes

*I was told in ux.stackexchange that this question is better suited for biology.stackexchange, so, here we go ;).*

I have a 50Hz 4k monitor (28 inch and using 1920x1080 scaling - so, the text is super smooth and pixels are non visible from my 90 cm distance as I sit) but I can't set it higher to something like 60Hz.

Does this equals to some problems long term or the 10Hz difference is not something I should be worried at all?

Comment: Welcome. Why would any refresh rate be harmful to your eyes?

Comment: @AliceD people have different views on this topic. A lot of people say higher refresh rate is easy on eyes. That indirectly says 60Hz is less good for your eyes. See this https://superuser.com/questions/302415/is-60hz-refresh-rate-as-bad-as-i-believe-it-is The discussion in comments is not clear.

Comment: Also, the more I read that higher refresh rate like 120Hz is easy on eyes, why we still have 60Hz monitors? They would potentially be straining eyes more for maybe half of the customers?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, flickering can cause eye fatigue and headaches, but 50Hz vs 60Hz would only be relevant if your 4K screen was built in the old CRT technology, which certainly not the case.

Todays screens do not flicker at the refresh rate frequency, instead you should check the backlight flicker, which is, sadly, not always disclosed  by the manufacturer.

Read more at: https://www.rtings.com/monitor/tests/motion/image-flicker